# Wordpress Codeless Slider Responsive Issue

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

If you visit my website so far, http://trulydesigns.com/ you will notice that everything looks in order.

If you visit the web page via mobile such as an iPhone 5s the slider looks out of place. http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//trulydesigns.com&w=320&h=568&a=37&s=1

```
function createSlider(){
    global $cl_redata;
    if(isset($cl_redata['codeless_slider_height']) && $cl_redata['codeless_slider_height'] != '100%')
        $height = $cl_redata['codeless_slider_height'];
    elseif(! isset($cl_redata['codeless_slider_height']))
        $height = '450';
    else
        $height = 'fullscreen'; 

    $this->height = $height;

    $extra_class = '';
    if($cl_redata['slider_parallax']) 
        $extra_class .= ' parallax_slider';

    $output = '<div class="codeless_slider_swiper '.esc_attr($extra_class).'" style="'.(($height == 'fullscreen')?'':'height:'.$height.'px').'">';
        $output .= '<div class="loading"><i class="moon-spinner icon-spin"></i></div>';
        $output .= '<div class="codeless_slider_wrapper" data-start="transform: translateY(0px);" data-'.(($height == 'fullscreen')?'1440':$height).'="transform: translateY(-500px);">';
            $output .= '<div class="codeless-slider-container swiper-parent swiper_slider codeless_slider"  data-slidenumber="1" data-height="'.esc_attr($height).'">';
                $output .= '<div class="pagination-parent nav-thumbflip nav-slider">
                                <a class="prev" href="">
                                    <span class="icon-wrap"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></span>
                                    <div class="text">'.__('PREV','codeless').'</div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="next" href="">
                                    <span class="icon-wrap"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></span>
                                    <div class="text">'.__('NEXT','codeless').'</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>';
                $output .= '<div class="swiper-wrapper">';

    $this->output[] = $output;
}
```

This is a snippet of the "codeless_slider.php", somewhere in my files it's pulling "min-height: 236.97522816166884px;height: 236.97522816166884px;" and I can't figure where from, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those values are calculated by the jquery that is controlling the slider output, which is probably minified and going to be a nightmare to crawl through and modify. My advice, having done this with a different slider, is to write style rules to make it look the way you want it, overriding the defaults with `!important` declarations

Comment: @CreMedian How on earth did I not think of that, damn! thank you, its how it should be now.

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted my comment as an answer. I would be grateful if you accepted it to close your question out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be tricky because you use a plugin to not have to build it yourself, but sometimes plugins inject code and you have to learn how it is built in order to make it work the way you want anyway.

While learning Wordpress development, I learned to be best friends with the DOM inspector in Chrome and to use the `!important` declaration to overwrite style rules. It looks like you could do that here with success.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This code is from a Premium WordPress theme, so in any case you can ask their support forum on

https://codeless.co/support/